# Deploying multiple same EJB with different persistance

Tags: jakarta-ee

I need to deploy the same EJB multiple times. Each EJB will have its own context name identifying it on Glassfish as a separate application. Each EJB has their own persistence unit etc.

I then need to connect from the another application to each of these EJBs.
I'm not sure how to specify which EJB to connect to.

I've read about remote interfaces, but I'm not sure how to specify and inject the correct EJB required.

Answer (score 0):

Not totally sure but as far as i know, you could probably do it if you have different interfaces or jndi names on the bean.Something like below might work..

```
import javax.ejb.Remote;
@Remote
public interface HelloWorld{
   public void sayHello(String name);
}


import javax.ejb.Stateless;
@Stateless(mappedName=”ejb/HelloWorld”)
public class HelloWorldBean implements HelloWord  {
    public void sayHello(String name)  {
       System.out.println(“First .Hello ” + name + ” It’s Working!”);
    }
}


import javax.ejb.Stateless;
@Stateless(mappedName=”ejb/HelloWorld1”)
public class HelloWorldBean implements HelloWorld {
  public void sayHello(String name) {
      System.out.println(“Second Hello ” + name + ” It’s Working!”);
  }
}
```

Comment: This would require me to update the bean every time I need to make a new deployment. The only other solution I can think of is using Web services. In this way I can deploy the same web service on different URLs, and then in my client call the correct URL.
If I'm correct, this would be more overhead than using remote interfaces. But I'm not sure.

Comment: Yes, my solution would require you to update the bean for every deployment but you could save the change to the class and just update the deployment descriptor if you move the jndi name to a deployment descriptor instead of using it with the @Stateless annotation. Something like this - see my next comment.

Comment: `<session>
      <ejb-name>HelloWorldBean</ejb-name>
      <mapped-name>ejb/HelloWorld</mapped-name>
      <ejb-class>com.xyz.HelloWorldBean</ejb-class>

      <persistence-context-ref>
        <persistence-context-ref-name>em/database</persistence-context-ref-name>
        <persistence-unit-name>EntityProviderName</persistence-unit-name> <!-- gets defined in persistence.xml -->
        <persistence-context-type>Transaction</persistence-context-type>
      </persistence-context-ref>
</session>`

Comment: sorry, i could not format the xml code as comments dont seem to take the formatting shortcuts. btw, the xml above would go into ejb-jar.xml